# Multiple users triggering the same macro

Tags: vba, excel

New user here! I'm creating an improved work tracker which contains a 'Sort' button which triggers a macro to copy and paste completed work rows from the 'Outstanding Work' tab to a 'Completed' tab (depending on the month in which it was completed, with column U containing the month number based on completion date) using the following sub:

```
Sub MoveCompleted()

Dim bottomL As Integer

bottomL = Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Outstanding").Range("U5:U" & bottomL)
    If c.Value = "1" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Jan").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "2" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Feb").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "3" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Mar").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "4" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Apr").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "5" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - May").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "6" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Jun").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "7" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Jul").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "8" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Aug").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "9" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Sep").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "10" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Oct").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "11" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Nov").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    If c.Value = "12" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - Dec").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Not only is this time consuming if dealing with a lot of data but there's a chance two users could trigger the macro at once and overwrite data on one of the completed tabs.

Are there any more efficient ways of doing this or is there any available code to prevent a user triggering the macro if it's already in use?
Thanks

**EDIT**

As requested by Mr. Wayne here is a screenshot of the Outstanding tab i want to move data from.

[Work Tracker - Outstanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmmUr.png)

Each of the Completed tabs match this one in terms of layout (including the blank header rows).
Once the 'Sort' button is clicked, i'd like the macro to look in column O for cells containing a date (in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format) and if found, move the values in cells A:N to the relevant 'Completed tab' (it currently moves the entire row but it's causing some file swelling issues due to the formatting). The same thing needs to happen in column N ('referred') however there's only a single 'Referred' tab to move to.
I then have secondary macros which delete the rows from 'Outstanding' with a value in either 'N' or 'O'.

As an update to my original query regarding multiple users running the same macro; I've implemented a step where once the sort button is clicked, VB opens a saved .txt file and keeps it open until the macro has run. If another user tries to run the macro, VB checks if the .txt file is already open and, if so, terminates. Seems to be working nicely for now so thanks for everyone's input so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Unrelated, but I believe all your `If` statements can be condensed into one line - `c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Completed - " & Format(DateSerial(2017, c.Value, 1), "mmm")).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.  (I.e. create a dummy date using `c.Value` as the month, then format it as `"mmm"`, and use that in the worksheet name.)

Comment: Ahh brilliant, I was hoping one of you most helpful people would be able to show me how to condense that! Thanks

Comment: You need to qualify what sheet `Rows.Count` is expected to occur on, otherwise it's going to use whatever the active sheet is, and that may not be the row count you wanted. e.g. for `c.Value = 12`, you want `Worksheets("Completed - Dec").Range("A" & Worksheets("Completed - Dec").Rows.Count)...`  and also `bottomL = Sheets("Outstanding").Range("A" & Sheets("Outstanding").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Also, when you say a macro will be triggered by two users at once, how do you mean? AFAIK when one user has the File open, and someone else goes to open it too, it will only allow a "Read Only" version to be used (or, will ask them to save a local copy, and use that). How could two users run the macro on the *same open file*?  And finally, do you want to copy the formatting, or just the values? If it's just the values, this can be a real quick macro that should run in say 1 second or less.  How long is the macro taking now?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, it's a shared workbook which the users will access several times each during the day. I just need the values but there are some dates in there I'll need to keep as is format-wise.  I tested it with a colleague yesterday and it took several seconds to run (which should be reduced by the condensed if formula) so maybe I'm being overly cautious but I've run into this issue before with shared workbooks so just want to make sure I've covered everything. Thanks for your help

Comment: The "condensed `If` formula" won't noticeably improve run times - the copy will be taking almost all the execution time (and you will still be doing one of those per row) - the time to execute the current `If` statements themselves (i.e. to determine whether they are `True` or `False`) would be miniscule in comparison to the time taken to copy the row..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a condensed version of the code, with the `Range()` and `Rows.Count` properly anchored to the sheet I believe you want.  Also, I'm assuming you just need the cell values, which you can do quicker by setting two ranges equal to eachother.  This saves some time, as you can skip the clipboard completely (`.Copy`).  (Kudos to @YowE3K for the `If` simplification).

```
Sub MoveCompleted()

Dim bottomL As Integer

With Sheets("Outstanding")
    bottomL = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Sheets("Outstanding").Range("U5:U" & bottomL)
    With Worksheets("Completed - " & Format(DateSerial(2017, c.Value, 1), "mmm"))
        .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = Sheets("Outstanding").Rows(c).EntireRow.Value
    End With
Next c

End Sub
```

You can tweak as necessary.  I wasn't sure if you wanted the `Completed - Jan` rows to actually match the `Sheets("Outstanding")` row, or you just needed the cell value.   Also note you're basing the `bottomL` after the amount of cells in column A.  ...but then using column U to get the data.  What do you expect to happen if Column A has, say, only 4 values? Then your `.Range("U5:U4")` will likely throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone fully data blind for the day so I'll revisit it in the morning and try what you suggested. I'll let you know how I get on! Thanks again!

Comment: @LewisWalker I think it'll work for you. But again, I wasn't sure if you just wanted the "outstanding" sheet's *cell value*, or the entire row's value to be copied over. If it doesn't work exactly like you want, perhaps post a quick sample of your two sheets (data table, or a screen shot) and what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Just being picky (but I aren't I always?!?) but if `.Rows.Count` was different between `Sheets("Outstanding")` and `Worksheets("Completed - Jan")` etc (and they shouldn't be if they are in the same workbook) then the `.Columns.Count` will also be different and that will mean the ranges on the left and right side of the assignment will have different dimensions, which will cause the assignment to fail (I think).

Comment: I'm realising I should really have given more information! I need the entire row of data to be exported from outstanding onto the relevant completed tab but only once the piece of work has been marked as 'complete' (i.e. a date added to column U). I then have a second macro which deletes the completed work from the outstanding tab (after its been copied, obviously) but I'm sure you cleverer folk can probably tell me how to do that at the same time. I'll have a look with fresh eyes tomorrow and hopefully I can explain it in a way that makes sense!

Comment: @LewisWalker - Just add **one** `If` statement around the copy saying `If c.Value > 0 Then`

Comment: @LewisWalker - Sorry, I was going to mention in my previous comment that it was only in relation to your "but only once the piece of work has been marked as 'complete' " comment.  Someone came along and asked me a work question (how rude of them!!) and I pressed enter before I finished my comment.

Comment: @YowE3K always good to be picky! ...Am I missing something, where does he have `Columns.count`?

Comment: I just meant that your `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = Sheets("Outstanding").Rows(c).EntireRow.Value` statement is implicitly using `Columns.Count` because you are saying `EntireRow` (i.e. a range that is 1 row x .Columns.Count columns) and, if that was being done across different Excel workbook versions, would probably fail if you tried to copy 16384 columns to whatever the old number of columns was.

Comment: I suspect that only one workbook is involved, so I don't think that there is really any issue - as I said I am just being picky.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the input. I've since had a thought - the range is currently set to column U which contains the month number returned from the Completion date in column O (which is there for reporting purposes). The formula in column U is autopopulated down to 5000 lines which i'm assuming will slow down the whole operation. I'm therefore looking at changing my c.Value range to column O which contains the actual completion date(in a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format), however i'm not sure how to amend the '& Format(DateSerial...' section of BruceWaynes code to reflect. Any ideas?

Comment: @LewisWalker, can you post a sample of the data and the expected output?